# Trying to make a debounce timer/interrupt routine on pic16 i asm

Tags: assembly, timer, interrupt, pic, mplab

I am trying to get my head around how these timers and interrupts work 
and I figured that a debounce routine for a button would be a good way to start, since I need it for a project in school

I set this code up as best I could, but I'm pretty sure somethings wrong.
I don't really have the hardware to test it, but i would like to have it ready for school in a few days.

Could anyone please take a look at this code and tell me if I'm on the right track?
the idea is to fire an interrupt on timer0 and then count the number of times the button bounces in the same time window as timer0 will count down again. If the button is "pressed" 20 times then i hope that enough time has passed so that the button is done bouncing.

Q1 can i use timer0 for both telling the code how often to fire an interrupt and use it to test for if 20 presses are felt within the time timer0 counts?

I have a feeling that either I'm really close or i'm totally off. Please help me
I feel like I'm missing something (like a retfie)

I did not include all of the init part of the code and i left out variable declaration and reset and int vector setup, but it's just like in the datasheet

```
 BANKSEL INTCON
 MOVLW B'10100000'
 MOVWF INTCON

 BANKSEL OPTION_REG
 MOVLW B'11000111'  ;FOSC4mhz/4, 1:256 prescaler
 MOVWF OPTION_REG

 BANKSEL TMR0
 MOVLW B'10110010'  ;178 to get a cycle of around 20mS
 MOVWF TMR0

 MOVLW B'00010100'
 MOVWF BOUNCECOUNTER        ;count down from 20
 GOTO MAIN

ISR
 BTFSC INTCON, 2    ;TEST TIMER0 OVERFLOW FLAG
 RETFIE
 GOTO TEST

TEST 
 BTFSC INTCON, 2
 GOTO DECIDE
 DECFSZ TMR0 
 BTFSC PORTA, 0     ;TEST FOR BUTTON PRESS
 GOTO DECIDE
 DECFSZ BOUNCECOUNTER       ;DECREMENT BOUNCECOUNTER EVERY TIME A HIGH TO LOW ON PORTA  
 GOTO TEST
 GOTO DECIDE

DECIDE 
 BTFSC INTCON, 2    ;TEST TIMER0 OVERFLOW FLAG  
 BTFSS STATUS, Z    ;TEST IF BOUNCECOUNTER REACHES ZERO 
 GOTO TEST
 BTFSS INTCON, 2
 GOTO NOTPRESSED
 GOTO BPRESSED      ;LOOP TIMER0 AND TEST FOR BUTTON PRESS

BPRESSED
 BCF INTCON, 2      ;CLEAR TIMER0 OVERFLOW FLAG
 MOVLW 0x000
 MOVWF BOUNCECOUNTER
;TOGGLE BETWEEN AWESOME STUFF

NOTPRESSED
 BCF INTCON, 2 
 MOVLW 0x000
 MOVWF BOUNCECOUNTER
 RETFIE

MAIN

 GOTO MAIN
    END
```

Comment: My way is to test the button press *within* a free-run timer ISR running at say 50 Hz. Increment a counter if the button is pressed, zero the counter if it is not. When the necessary (say 3) number of counts is reached, the button-press event is flagged to the "user". The button sensing being done from the input's level, not its transition.

Comment: if i understand you right. you would use a separate timer to run while you count the button presses?

Comment: I don't count the button-presses, I count the number of times the input is in the "pressed" state, in the regular timer interrupt. My counter goes upward, yours goes down, but in your code, you don't reset that counter in the way you first initialise it - you set it to 0. More generally, if you don't mind, I have found in embedded work that a regular "heartbeat" interrupt is useful for many things, and I always have one, for example you can maintain a counter which is useful for a clock, and for timing in general for "user" functions, similar to using `clock()` in C programs.

Comment: do you mind giving me an example on how you you write that peace of heartbeat interrupt code?

Comment: Isn't a free run timer configuration in the data sheet? In the ISR, you clear the timer interrupt status, and increment your clock count.

Comment: i have looked deeply into the datasheet and i can't find anything about it in there
i'm using PIC16F1827

Comment: It is all there in the data sheet. Timer 0 (8 bit) and Timer 1 (16-bit) can both be set to interrupt on overflow, and both may have a clock prescaler.